# Petición GET o DELETE a una tabla MySQL usando fetch() filtrando por más de un campo

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, fetch, filtro

En el código siguiente:

- gasto: es una tabla de una base de datos MySQL
- codgas.value: es el valor de un input text

Además:

- campo1: es el primer campo de la tabla gastos y tiene valores repetidos.
- campo2: es otro campo cualquiera de la tabla gastos.

En estas condiciones, la petición GET retorna todos los registros de la tabla gastos con `campo1 === codgas.value`

La duda concreta es:

- ¿Cómo debe modificarse el código para que la petición retorne solo los registros con:

`campo1 === codgas.value` && `campo2 === valor1`?

```
   let valor1 = "xxx"
    url1 = "http://localhost:3000/api/gasto/
    fetch(url+codgas.value,{
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    })
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>{
      let nuevoDato=[]
      nuevoDato.push(data)
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Noto una confusion entre los parametros a una api (que no tienen ni siquiera que ser iguales a los de la tabla) y lo que pasa atras.. vos queres saber como pasar parametros en una peticion get.. el resto, esta de mas.. y tu problema siguiente es como tomarlos y hacer la consulta a la tabla...

Comment: Ome, es el servidor quien define las rutas aceptadas en la api y que es lo que devuelve para cada petición. Asi que si quieres que TAL ruta acepta otro campo mas y que la consulta dependa de este otro campo, no hay ningun problema pero eso teienes que definirlo en el servidor.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Entiendo que se haga difícil entender lo que estoy preguntando. Tal vez mi nivel de conocimientos impida consultar correctamente y eso, por ahora, no puedo solucionarlo. No obstante he tenido respuestas que me han servido mucho: la de @ferter3006 y otras que han sido borradas. Tal vez alguien pueda explicarme el motivo de los comentarios borrados, ya que soy nuevo en esta plataforma. Gracias.